# Multicolumn and hline

Tags: tables, multicolumn

If I run the following code I got a table with a multicolumn of 5 but if I place an `\hline` before the multicolumn as seen in the code it closes all the table in the upper part. How can I close only the 5 multicolumn leaving the other part without lines?

```
\begin{tabular}{|r{1.5cm}|c{1.5cm}|c{1.5cm}|c{1.5cm}|c{1.5cm}|c{2.5cm}|c{1.33cm}|c{1.3cm}|c{2cm}|}
\hline %with this command the line is for all the table not just the 5 columns
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Mensual} \\
\hline
& L\'iquido & S. Social & IRPF & TOTAL & Anual l\'iquido & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Total Anual\\ 
Nombre & (A) & (B) & (C) & A+B+C & (D) = A $\times$ pagas& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Por Caja o ``B''} & (D) + Caja\\ \hline
Jos\'e & 2.563,56 \euro & 172,82 \euro & 864,12 \euro & 3.600,5 \euro & \textbf{38.453 \euro} & 21.295 \euro & 9.851 \euro & \textbf{69.599 \euro}\\ \hline
Pedro & 1.949,50 \euro & 170,60 \euro & 669,50 \euro & 2.789,6 \euro & \textbf{41.844 \euro} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{41.844 \euro}\\ \hline
Antonio & 2.240,72 \euro & 181,99 \euro & 601,84 \euro & 3.024,6 \euro & \textbf{26.889 \euro} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{10.125 \euro}& \textbf{37.014 \euro}\\ \hline
Lina & 1.870,12 \euro & 152,01 \euro & 334,13 \euro & 2.356,3 \euro & \textbf{28.052 \euro} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{28.052 \euro}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: your title and tag mentions multirow (for the `multirow` package) but the code shown foes not use `\multirow` but `\multicolumn` (and is not a complete example that anyone can run. Please make the question clearer.

Comment: `r{1.5cm}`  and `c{1.5cm}` are syntax errors unless you are using some very non standard package.

Comment: E.g. `\cline{1-5}` after removing errors in your code.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Next time I'll try to be more accurate. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative with use of `siunitx` and similar "open look" of table as propsed [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/5001/mico) in his answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\B}{\fontseries{b}\selectfont} % renew def. for non-extended bold font
\robustify\B


\begin{document}

\begingroup
    \sisetup{detect-weight,
            output-decimal-marker={,},
            group-minimum-digits=4,
            group-separator={.}
            }
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \small
\begin{tabular}{@{}l
                S[table-format=4.2]
           *{2}{S[table-format=3.2]}
                S[table-format=4.1]
                S[table-format=4.0]
                S[table-format=5.0]
                S[table-format=4.0]
                S[table-format=5.0]
                @{}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Mensual}   &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
\thead[b]{Nombre}
    &   {\thead[b]{L\'iquido\\ (A)}}
        &   {\thead[b]{S. Social\\ (B)}}
            &   {\thead[b]{IRPF\\ (C)}}
                &   {\thead[b]{TOTAL\\ (A + B + C)}}
                    &   {\thead[b]{Anual l\'iquido (D)\\
                        $=(\mathrm{A})\times \mathrm{paagas}$}}
                        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead[b]{Por Caja o ``B''}}
                            &   {\thead[b]{Total Anual\\
                                $(D) + \mathrm{Caja}$}}                              \\
    \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
    & {\euro} & {\euro} & {\euro} & {\euro} & {\euro} & {\euro} & {\euro} & {\euro} \\
     \midrule
Jos\'e  & 2 563.56  & 172.82 & 864.12  & 3 600.5 & \B 38 453 & 21 295 & 9 851  & \B 69 599 \\ Pedro   & 1 949.50  & 170.60 & 669.50  & 2 789.6 & \B 41 844
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sin Datos}    & \B 41 844         \\
Antonio & 2 240.72  & 181.99 & 601.84  & 3 024.6 & \B 26 889
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{10.125}       & \B 37 014        \\
Lina    & 1 870.12  & 152.01 & 334.13 & 2 356.3  & \B 28 052
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sin Datos}    & \B 28 052        \\
\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, there's no need to specify exact widths for any of the columns, especially as automatic line wrapping would seem to be inappropriate. Just use the "standard" column types -- `l`, `c`, and `r` -- instead.

Your table does have quite few columns, and it thus won't fit on a normal-sized page in portrait mode (unless you select a minuscule font size). I therefore suggest you typeset the table in landscape mode instead -- using, say, the `sidewaystable` environment provided by the `rotating` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}  % or 'portuguese' ?
\usepackage{array,eurosym,rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}  
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|*{8}{c|}}
\cline{1-5}
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Mensual} \\
\hline
Nombre & L\'iquido & S. Social & IRPF & Total & Anual l\'iquido & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Por Caja o ``B''} & Total Anual\\ 
& (A) & (B) & (C) & (A)+(B)+(C) & (D) = A$\times$pagas& \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & (D) + Caja\\ 
\hline
Jos\'e & 2.563,56 \euro & 172,82 \euro & 864,12 \euro & 3.600,5 \euro & \textbf{38.453 \euro} & 21.295 \euro & 9.851 \euro & \textbf{69.599 \euro}\\ 
\hline
Pedro & 1.949,50 \euro & 170,60 \euro & 669,50 \euro & 2.789,6 \euro & \textbf{41.844 \euro} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{41.844 \euro}\\ 
\hline
Antonio & 2.240,72 \euro & 181,99 \euro & 601,84 \euro & 3.024,6 \euro & \textbf{26.889 \euro} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{10.125 \euro}& \textbf{37.014 \euro}\\ 
\hline
Lina & 1.870,12 \euro & 152,01 \euro & 334,13 \euro & 2.356,3 \euro & \textbf{28.052 \euro} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{28.052 \euro}\\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: You should also give some thought to giving your table a more "open" look, in order to make it look more inviting and welcoming to your readers. To achieve such a look, do consider (i) getting rid of all vertical lines and most horizontal lines and (ii) using the macros of the `booktabs` package for the remaining horizontal lines. To further enhance readability, consider putting the euro symbols in a separate header row.

[image]

```
\documentclass[spanish]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}  % or 'portuguese' ?
\usepackage{eurosym,rotating,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} 
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l*{8}{c}@{}}

\multicolumn{5}{@{}c}{Mensual} \\
\cmidrule(r){1-5}
Nombre & L\'iquido & S. Social & IRPF & Total & Anual l\'iquido & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Por Caja o ``B''} & Total Anual\\ 
& (A) & (B) & (C) & (A)+(B)+(C) & (D) = (A)$\times$pagas& & & (D) + Caja\\ 
\cmidrule(lr){7-8}
& (\euro) & (\euro) & (\euro) & (\euro) & (\euro) & (\euro) & (\euro) & (\euro) \\
\midrule
Jos\'e & 2.563,56 & 172,82 & 864,12 & 3.600,50 & \textbf{38.453} & 21.295 & 9.851 & \textbf{69.599}\\ 
\addlinespace
Pedro & 1.949,50 & 170,60 & 669,50 & 2.789,60 & \textbf{41.844} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{41.844}\\ 
\addlinespace
Antonio & 2.240,72 & 181,99 & 601,84 & 3.024,55 & \textbf{26.889} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{10.125\,\euro}& \textbf{37.014}\\ 
\addlinespace
Lina & 1.870,12 & 152,01 & 334,13 & 2.356,26 & \textbf{28.052} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{28.052}\\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great!! Excellent solutions both. I will give to the table more "open" look. Thanks and regards.

Comment: And by the way. Spanish!! Always spanish!! Nothing to do with Portugal ;)

Comment: @José - So I guessed right, at least on the language option...

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|p{1.5cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.2cm}|p{1.5cm}|p{0.9cm}|p{0.6cm}|p{1.2cm}|}
    \hline %with this command the line is for all the table not just the 5 columns 
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Mensual} &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{}\\ %needed to insert line break 
    \hline
    & L\'iquido & S. Social & IRPF & TOTAL & Anual l\'iquido & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{} & Total Anual\\ 
    Nombre & (A) & (B) & (C) & A+B+C & (D) = A $\times$ pagas& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Por Caja o ``B''} & (D) + Caja\\ \hline
    & \euro & \euro & \euro & \euro &\euro & \euro & \euro & \euro \\\hline
    Jos\'e & 2.563,56 & 172,82 & 864,12  & 3.600,5 & \textbf{38.453} & 21.295 & 9.851  & \textbf{69.599 }\\ \hline
    Pedro & 1.949,50 & 170,60  & 669,50  & 2.789,6 & \textbf{41.844 } & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{41.844 }\\ \hline
    Antonio & 2.240,72  & 181,99 & 601,84  & 3.024,6  & \textbf{26.889 } & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{10.125}& \textbf{37.014}\\ \hline
    Lina & 1.870,12  & 152,01 & 334,13 & 2.356,3  & \textbf{28.052} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Sin Datos}& \textbf{28.052 }\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image: eurotbl]

Comment: Unless the text block happens to be quite wide -- a subject about which the OP, unfortunately, provided no information -- this table won't fit on either an a4-sized or a letter-sized page in portrait mode.